# Fullcalendar height and no scrollbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, fullcalendar

I'am new on stackoverflow and i have a question after day's of searching and editing i can't find what i wanna do.

I'am using CGCalendar in my CMSMS website, the CGCalendar using Fullcalender to view the events and the calender.

I set the calendar in a div: `div#fullcalendar{width:60%;}`
But when it is 60% of my website i get a scrollbar on the right side of the calendar.
I wanna remove that scrollbar en make the days height lower.

I was looking in: 'lib/fullcalendar/fullcalendar.js' but i can't find the right way to change this.

Maybe i can change it in the CSS but there also i can't find it.

Can someone help me to make these changes? and explain where i need to make this changes? in the CSS or the `fullcalendar.js`

My javascript is not so good, sow changes are difficult for me.

Thanks you for helping me.

[image: Calendar]

Answer (score 0):

Did you try

```
div#fullcalendar{
   width:60%;
   overflow-y:hidden;
}
```